# How to filter away resolved issues that did not spend time in progress?

Tags: jira, jql

Given a workflow where issues can be **BACKLOG**, **IN PROGRESS** and **DONE**, I want a filter that **DOESN'T** show **done** issues that never spent time **in progress**.

It is a reasonably common situation for issues to be moved directly from backlog to done because they e.g. got canceled or evolved into multiple other issues. I'd like to track issues that we've completed, and those "no progress" issues should not show up in it.

I have alternatives to pursue if this isn't possible in JQL, but I've played around with queries like `status changed BEFORE -5d` and I can't *quite* tell if Jira offers the kind of searching I want.. maybe someone can answer with certainty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to find issues that were never in the `In Progress` status at any point in time, you can use a query like this:

`project=MYPROJ and status=Done and status was not in ("In Progress")`